# Blender page animation collada file in Scenekit

Tags: animation, export, file-format

I am currently developing through blender and Scenekit.

I'm trying to create a book animation in Scenekit. I've created a page based on the following video:

https://youtu.be/eBIxcm-T3Oo

And I converted that animation into a Collada file.

[image]

However, when I import this file from Scenekit, only Rotation animations will work. Mesh deformations do not work.

Is there a way to make this work in Scenekit? I am very annoyed by this.

Please let me know if there is another way.

Comment: Why is there a tag for animation-nodes ?

Comment: Fixed tags. Deformation and shape shifting animations are mostly non-exportable from most applications since they are very specific data, with the possible exception of armature based deformations

Comment: Very very thanks for your apply. Thanks!! :)